# How to remove the list of this specific format in Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to remove the list of these kind of list with this specific format [xxx]. I can't get text of a list. I can't find a way to select only the list of that format for apply later "ActiveDocument.Lists(X).RemoveNumbers". Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Is there a place in the web that the Word lists are explained in deep? I have tried to search info but seems there is no many.

Comment: You need to read up on ListTemplates, a particularly Arcane object in Word.  To remove the list try looking under list styles and delete the relevant sttyle (if indeed the numbering comes from a style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Finally I found a way of do this.

Just iterate over the list and:

`ActiveDocument.Lists(X).Range.ListFormat.ListString`

The result will be "[0001]" for the first one, then parse the result and if it match remove the list with `ActiveDocument.Lists(X).RemoveNumbers`